# Одинаковые поля в нескольких таблицах в одном запросе

Tags: php, mysql

В одном запросе MYSQL данные берутся из 3 таблиц в 2-х из которых поля с одинаковыми именами - t1.alt_name и t3.alt_name. Вот код:

```
$query = mysql_query(
'SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.title, 
  t1.autor, 
  t1.date, 
  t1.category, 
  t1.short_story, 
  ***t1.alt_name***, 
  t2.images, 
  t2.news_id, 
  t3.id, 
  t3.alt_name
FROM
  dle_post AS t1, dle_images AS t2, dle_category AS t3
WHERE
  t1.id = t2.news_id, t1.category = t3.id
ORDER BY
  date DESC') or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
```

Подскажите как правильно скорректировать этот запрос чтобы далее в коде, в массиве это бы разные переменные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно назначить столбцу с конфликтующим именем псевдоним при помощи ключевого слова AS, точно так же, как вы назначаете псевдонимы таблицам в конструкции FROM

```
$query = mysql_query(
'SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.title,
  t1.autor,
  t1.date,
  t1.category,
  t1.short_story,
  t1.alt_name AS t1_alt_name,
  t2.images,
  t2.news_id,
  t3.id,
  t3.alt_name
FROM
  dle_post AS t1,
  dle_images AS t2,
  dle_category AS t3
WHERE
  t1.id = t2.news_id, t1.category = t3.id
ORDER BY date DESC') or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
```

Далее в результирующей таблице обращаться к такому полю можно по имени `t1_alt_name`, так как будто в таблице имеется столбец с таким именем.